# Proving $|CH| = 2|OM|$ of $\triangle ABC$ of which $O$ is the circumcenter and $H$ is the orthocenter.

Tags: proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Let $ABC$ be a triangle as shown in the figure below, where $O$ is its circumcenter and $H$ is its orthocenter. $AB$ is the opposite side of the climax point $C$, and $OM$ is perpendicular to $AB$.

How to prove that $|CH| = 2|OM|$?

[image]

$G$ is the centroid of the triangle. As the circumcenter, centroid and orthocenter (respectively $O$, $G$, and $H$) of the circle is collinear, we can get two specific triangle $CGH$ and $OMG$.

Showing both the triangle similar to each other by their respective angle, we can get the proportion of their 2 different length. If we consider the point $G$, then we can get $|CG|:|GM| = 2:1$. Thus we can easily prove this.

However, we can reverse the proof showing that $|CH|$ is equal to $2|OM|$ (It is included in our textbook as a corollary or something other). If we go with this process, it will lead to something **contradictory**.

Because of claiming the $G$ as centroid of the triangle, we have already used the above condition which needs to be proved.

So, is there any other method to prove that $|CH|=2|OM|$?

Comment: If $CH=2OM$ was proved while proving another equality, then you already have an independent proof of that.

Comment: I think, I have been futile to clearify my text. While proving another equality, I just used CH = 2OM as a preknowledge, not was proved in that proof. So I wanted a distinctive proof of above condition which has been proposed.

Comment: Using the property of O,G,H to be on the Euler line with GH=2OG, triangle GHC is the homothetic image of triangle GOM by the homothety centered in G with ratio $-2$, that's all... See the same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4432096/305862).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

The most ellegant proof (at least in my opinion) is vector based:

Vectors $\vec{CH}$ and $\vec{OM}$ are parallel as well as vectors $\vec{AH}$ and $\vec{ON}$ and therefore:

$$\vec{OM}=\alpha\vec{CH}$$

$$\vec{ON}=\beta\vec{AH}$$

...for some real values of $\alpha,\beta$.

Segment MN connects midpoints of sides $AB$ and $BC$ and therefore:

$$\vec{MN}=\frac12\vec{AC}=\frac12(\vec{AH}+\vec{HC})=\frac12\vec{AH}-\frac12\vec{CH}\tag{1}$$

On the other side it is obvious that:

$$\vec{MN}=\vec{MO}+\vec{ON}=-\vec{OM}+\vec{ON}=-\alpha\vec{CH}+\beta\vec{AH}\tag{2}$$

From (1) and (2) you get that:

$$\frac12\vec{AH}-\frac12\vec{CH}=-\alpha\vec{CH}+\beta\vec{AH}$$

$$(\frac12-\beta)\vec{AH}+(\alpha-\frac12)\vec{CH}=0\tag{3}$$

Vectors $\vec{AH}$ and $\vec{CH}$ are not parallel! If you multiply these vectors with some real factors different from zero, you still get vectors that are not parallel (vectors are just stretched). Sum of two vectors that are not parallel cannot be zero. So (3) can be valid only if both scalars are equal to zero:

$$\frac12 - \beta =0,  \ \ \alpha-\frac12=0$$

...which simply means that $\alpha=\beta=\frac12$. Consequentially:

$$\vec{OM}=\frac12\vec{CH}$$

$$OM=\frac12 CH$$

Comment: Outstanding solution, Oldboy. But my question is that which term is better for AH and CH vector?  Collinearity or obliqueness? I didn't understand and I need more clarification about what you said that if we multiply (3) vectors with some real factors different from zero, we still get vectors that aren't collinear. If you get time, please explain that.

Comment: I think that you are right. I have used "collinear" while in fact I meant "parallel". I'm going to correct that. Basically, if you have two vectors that are not parallel their sum cannot be zero! Multiply these two vectors with some scalars, it won't change their orientation in space. Non-parallel vectors will still be non-parallel and their sum cannot be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know Hamilton theorem? It says  $$\vec{OH}= \vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC} $$

So $$\vec{CH}=\vec{OH}- \vec{OC}= \vec{OA}+\vec{OB}   =2\vec{OM}   $$

Comment: No, I didn't know about it. You helped me to learn a new thing which is more appreciated. If possible, I will try to read about the personal details of Hamilton theorem.

Comment: @Aqua can you give a source

Comment: What is your languague? @Buraian

Comment: I can only read English @Aqua

Comment: https://web.evanchen.cc/geombook.html @Buraian