# Why is the distance from orthocenter to vertex twice the distance from circumcenter to opposite side?

Tags: geometry, triangles, triangle-centres

[image]

In the diagram above, $$2SP=AO$$ in description :

> line from orthocenter is 2 times of line from circumcenter.

But I remember, someone in MSE said It's Euler line (I have read Wikipedia article but that doesn’t my question). My question is why line from the orthocenter is 2 times of line from the circumcenter?

Here, S is circumcenter, G is centroid and O is orthocenter.

Book says :

> In $\triangle ABC$, the distance from the orthocenter O to A is OA, and the distance of the opposite line "BC" from the circumcenter S to the top of A is SP. $\therefore 2SP=AO$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135783/discussion-on-question-by-man-why-is-the-distance-from-orthocenter-to-vertex-twi).

Comment: @JeanMarie yes! That's the same question, I wonder that question was also asked by one of my countryman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Consider the following redrawn figure: remarkable points $H,G,O$ are aligned on the "Euler line" with

$$\vec{GH}=-2 \vec{GO}\tag{1}$$

(property also due to Euler). As a consequence triangle $GHC$ is the image of triangle $GOM_c$ by the homothety with center $G$ and ratio $-2$, giving the result.

[image]

2. Another kind of proof which does not use (1). Here is for example a copy of the classical book "College geometry" by Nathan Altshiller-Court. The proof relies on the construction of a diameter $CL$, allowing to say that $\angle LBC$ is a right angle, then spotting a parallelogram.)

[image]

(see as well [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666324/305862))

3. A completely different type of proof is based on Hamilton theorem (see page 2 [here](http://ijmttjournal.org/Volume-67/Issue-9/IJMTT-V67I9P508.pdf)).

$$\vec{OH}=\vec{OA}+\vec{OB}+\vec{OC}$$

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3100107/305862).

Comment: How can I verify that the segment OA' joins the midpoint of two of the right triangle BCL? Can't we directly prove that (using some other rules)? I have downloaded the book but it's also looking like magic to me :|

Comment: $OC$ being a radius of the circumcircle $(C)$ and $L$ being the 2nd intersection of line $OC$ with circle $(C)$, $CL$ is a diameter of circle $(C)$. Therefore $O$ is the midpoint of $CL$, As a consequence right triangles $OA'C$ and $LBC$ are similar in a ratio 2:1.

Comment: @JeanMarie: +1. Nice finds! Perhaps this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Blue You are right. I do it now.